# Kendo Tree View Keep displaying No records to display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview, kendo-treelist

I am working on kendo TreeView control and trying to display tree structure in the grid but I am always getting an error from the control No records to display.

Could any one please help me to identify my mistake.

```js
<body>
<div id="treelist"></div>
  <script>
  
   $(document).ready(function () {
            var dataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
                data: [
             { "UserId": 0, "ParentUserId": null, "Name": "Abhishek" },
             { "UserId": 1, "ParentUserId": 0, "Name": "Ravi" },
             { "UserId": 2, "ParentUserId": 1, "Name": "Manish" },
             { "UserId": 3, "ParentUserId": 1, "Name": "Anuj" },
             { "UserId": 4, "ParentUserId": null, "Name": "Shiv" },
             { "UserId": 5, "ParentUserId": null, "Name": "Ram" },
             { "UserId": 6, "ParentUserId": 5, "Name": "Kashi" },
             { "UserId": 7, "ParentUserId": 5, "Name": "Ekansh" },
             { "UserId": 8, "ParentUserId": 7, "Name": "Tanmay" },
             { "UserId": 9, "ParentUserId": 7, "Name": "Rahul" }
                ],

                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "UserId",
                        parentId: "ParentUserId",
                        fields: {
                            UserId: { type: "number", nullable: false },
                            ParentUserId: { field: "ParentUserId", nullable: true }
                        },
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#treelist").kendoTreeList({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                height: 540,
                columns: [{ field: "Name" }]
            });
        });
  </script>
  </body>
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: kendo-treeview, kendo-treelist are 2 different controls. Please remove unrelated tags.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect. No changes are to be done except '.js' files. Please update your following files and try again.

1. kendo.all.min.js (Kendo UI v2017.3.913)
2. jquery.min.js (jQuery v1.12.3 )